# What it takes to recreate fits.me in Flash? (Flash experts...)

Tags: flash

I'm just curious what's the real innovation in fits.me? Calculation? Stretching the image?

Just looking for some Flash expert comments...

**Update:** Missed out the URL(http://fits.me/)

Cheers,
Mickey

Answer (score 0):

if you look at the headers on the website it is just loading a lot of photographs. the actual 'innovation' here is only of a lot of content, the flash seems to be doing very little apart from holding the information and providing the algorithms for the sizing.

Answer (score 0):

The IT-side of the Fits.me is extremely light-weight. Therefore I guess, re-creating this in Flash would be rather simple. Indeed, we've been thinking of a flash version ourselves, as this would make it easier to embed it to other sites. So if You'd like to take up the task or seeing how to further develop Fits.me, it would be great to talk about it.
The back-end of Fits.me is slightly more complicated. Of each clothing item we make few thousand photos, which correspond to different body shapes and sizes. Get in touch with us.

Heikki from Fits.me

Comment: I've send an email to the main email on fits.me